# Dell Inspiron 1520 User Completely New To Ubuntu

Tags: inspiron

I have been a part of Ubuntu user population for about two hours right now.  After installing it on my Dell Inspiron 1520 that I bought so long ago, I jumped in really well, but, I have a few questions:

Once I check "Main Server" and check 'Canonical Partners' option and then the 'Broadcom Corporation: BCM-4311 802.11a/b/g" popped under 'Additional Drivers', how long does it take to install?

Also, I see GeForce 8600M (proprietary, tested), but when I try to install it as well, it gets stuck on the "Applying Changes" portion of what I am thinking is the UPDATE phase.

This is happening on both, and after 30 minutes, it is still stating, "Applying changes...", so what do I do?  A restart did not resolve this, it sticks about 1/4 inch in on the orange bar every time... what does a new Ubuntu user do?  Please advise.

Comment: After installing new Ubuntu, first install all the recommended updates and then proceed with installing any other software.

Comment: Okay, I have installed all of the recommended updates, Ubuntu 12.10 is up to date.  Yet, neither of the downloads for the wifi nor graphics cards finish downloading.  I am unable to, just a n00b, compile drivers, heck, wouldn't even know where to begin.  So what are my options now?  How do I get the DLs to finish so I can use these two items on Ubuntu?